# Orden de inicialización de variables estáticas en plantillas, en múltiples unidades de traducción

Tags: c++, c++11

Estaba haciendo pruebas, intentando crear identificadores únicos de clase que se autogeneren según sea necesario, sin utilizar código ejecutable (sin utilizar ninguna función que mantenga una variable).

Al final, llegué a esto:

```
namespace details {

template< typename T > struct ClassUIDBase {
    static T value;
};
template< typename T > T ClassUIDBase< T >::value = 0;

template< typename T > struct ClassUIDType : public ClassUIDBase< int > {
    static int value;
};
template< typename T > int ClassUIDType< T >::value = ++ClassUIDBase< int >::value;

} // namespace details.

using ClassUIDType = int;

template< typename T > ClassUIDType ClassUID( ) {
    return details::ClassUIDType< T >::value;
}
```

<sub>**Nota**: el objetivo es que compile en C++11, que no tiene variables `inline`. De ahí que la clase base sea `template` también. Es un *truco* para simularlas.</sub>

El código **aparenta** funcionar bien; si lo uso con varias clases, devuelve identificadores únicos de la forma esperada:

```
struct Test1 { };
struct Test2 { };
struct Test3 { };

int main( ) {
    std::cout << ClassUID< Test1 >( ) << '\n';
    std::cout << ClassUID< std::string >( ) << '\n';
    std::cout << ClassUID< Test2 >( ) << '\n';
    std::cout << ClassUID< Test3 >( ) << '\n';
    std::cout << ClassUID< Test1 >( ) << '\n';
    std::cout << ClassUID< std::string >( ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

La salida es la esperada: los identificadores se generan de forma secuencial, sin necesitar código que mantenga ninguna variable:

> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 1
> 2

Mi preocupación estriba en el modo de inicialización de variables globales usando varios archivos. Si divido el código de prueba en varios archivos, cada uno de ellos con su propia llamada a `ClassUID`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "classuid.hpp"

struct Test1 { };

void test1( ) {
    std::cout << "Test1: " << ClassUID< Test1 >( ) << '\n';
}
```

En mis pruebas he usado 4 archivos (`module1.cpp` ... `module4.cpp`), todos con la misma estructura. Y un `main.cpp` para llamar a las funciones `testX( )`:

```
void test1( );
void test2( );
void test3( );
void test4( );

int main( ) {
    test1( );
    test2( );
    test3( );
    test4( );

    test1( );
    test2( );
    test3( );
    test4( );

    return 0;
}
```

El resultado **sigue siendo el esperado**:

> Test1: 1
> Test2: 2
> Test3: 3
> Test4: 4
> Test1: 1
> Test2: 2
> Test3: 3
> Test4: 4

Mi duda: Al ser clases `template`, entiendo que se generará una variable

```
template< typename T > struct ClassUIDBase {
    static T value;
};
```

en cada unidad de traducción, y que el enlazador se encargará de eliminar las múltiples copias.

- ¿ Es posible que el código generado realice llamadas *en-orden-incorrecto* ? Es decir, que alguna variable estática *dentro* de una instanciación de `ClassUIDType` se instancie **antes** de que la variable estática *dentro* de `ClassUIDBase` esté correctamente inicializada ?